# Disable android edittext but allow clicks, or ellipsize enabled edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, kotlin, anko

So, I have an `EditText` in a `ScrollView`. Because this EditText can get quite long, we have decided to display only 6 lines at a time, ellipsize the rest, and then display a modal alert dialog to view/edit the full EditText.

However, this brings up two issues that I can't seem to get around. There are times when we need this EditText to be disabled - (after the screen it is on has been finalized).

However, as far as I can tell, if an EditText is disabled, its `OnClickListener` doesn't receive events. So my solution to that was to write this extension method:

```
fun EditText.disableButRemainClickable(softDisabled: Boolean) {
    if (softDisabled) {
        alpha = 0.5f
        isFocusable = false
        isFocusableInTouchMode = false
        isLongClickable = false
        isCursorVisible = false
    } else {
        alpha = 1f
        isFocusable = true
        isFocusableInTouchMode = true
        isLongClickable = true
        isCursorVisible = true
    }
}
```

This solves that problem. However, I now have a new problem. The ellipsize property doesn't work on an editText that is enabled. What can I do?

Comment: Why would you need an onClickListener when you disable the EditText. it is a confusing UI/UX design

Comment: With our style, it is not confusing.

Comment: I mean why would you edit something that's disabled.

Comment: You wouldn't. You click on it, it brings up a dialog where you can view the full text.

Comment: My guess would be to trim the String yourself before setting it in the EditText. And onClick it shows complete String. So maybe subString would help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can extend the `EditText` class and create your own `CustomEditText` class to maintain a state whether it is enabled or disabled.

Whenever you get the callback for `onClick`, you disable it and show the Dialog.

I think this might solve your problem.

Comment: Either way, no matter what I do, I can't get it ellipsized unless it is only a single line.